# HTML Canvas: zooming and panning with limitations

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I'm currently working on a mini project and need help with a little bit of code that i am using to zoom in and out and pan around a HTML canvas.

I would like to add limitations for:

1. How far you can zoom in and out (min and max size for the object).
2. How far you can pan around the screen. (the initial edges of the screen as the limit)

here is the code that I am using

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');  // selecting the canvas element in html file, the assigning to a variable

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

window.onload = function(){  
    
      
            trackTransforms(ctx);
            
    function Object (x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    
        this.draw = function () {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        };
    }
    
    function init(x, systemRadi, systemColor, scaleVal){
        var y = canvas.height/2
        var planets = [];
        for (var i= 0; i< systemRadi.length; i++){
            planets.push(new Object(x[i], y, systemRadi[i]*scaleVal, systemColor[i]))
        }
        animate(planets);
    
    }    
    function animate(planets){
            planets.forEach(function(Object) {
                Object.draw();
            }, this);
        }
    
    
    
    function main(){
        var scaleVal = 100;
        var r = [0.6957,0.0049,0.0121,0.0128,0.0068,0.143,0.1205,0.0511,0.0495,0.0028];
        var x =[-r[0]*scaleVal/4,11.6 + r[0]*scaleVal,21.6 + r[0]*scaleVal,29.9 + r[0]*scaleVal,45.6 + r[0]*scaleVal,155.8 + r[0]*scaleVal,286 + r[0]*scaleVal,574 + r[0]*scaleVal,899 + r[0]*scaleVal,1300 + r[0]*scaleVal];
        
        var col = ['rgb(242, 181, 50)','rgb(40, 8, 8)', 'rgb(124, 175, 35)','rgb(32, 32, 155)', 'rgb(196, 70, 39)', 'rgb(219, 125, 43)','rgb(219, 182, 37)', 'rgb(37, 140, 219)', 'rgb(37, 185, 219)', 'rgb(5, 10, 20)']
        init(x, r, col, scaleVal);
    
    
    }

    
    
    function redraw(){

          // Clear the entire canvas
          var p1 = ctx.transformedPoint(0,0);
          var p2 = ctx.transformedPoint(canvas.width,canvas.height);
          ctx.clearRect(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x-p1.x,p2.y-p1.y);

          ctx.save();
          ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
          ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
          ctx.restore();

          main();    // create image

        }
        redraw(); // redraw the image upon transformation

      var lastX=canvas.width/2, lastY=canvas.height/2;

      var dragStart,dragged;

      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
          document.body.style.mozUserSelect = document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = document.body.style.userSelect = 'none';
          lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
          lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
          dragStart = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
          dragged = false;
      },false);

      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
          lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
          lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
          dragged = true;
          if (dragStart){
            var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
            ctx.translate(pt.x-dragStart.x,pt.y-dragStart.y);
            redraw();
                }
      },false);

      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',function(evt){
          dragStart = null;
          if (!dragged) zoom(evt.shiftKey ? -1 : 1 );
      },false);

      var scaleFactor = 1.1;

      var zoom = function(clicks){
          var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
          ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
          var factor = Math.pow(scaleFactor,clicks);
          ctx.scale(factor,factor);
          ctx.translate(-pt.x,-pt.y);
          redraw();
      }

      var handleScroll = function(evt){
          var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta/40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
          if (delta) zoom(delta);
          return evt.preventDefault() && false;
      };
    
      canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',handleScroll,false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel',handleScroll,false);
 };

 
 // Adds ctx.getTransform() - returns an SVGMatrix
 // Adds ctx.transformedPoint(x,y) - returns an SVGPoint
 function trackTransforms(ctx){
      var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'svg');
      var xform = svg.createSVGMatrix();
      ctx.getTransform = function(){ return xform; };

      var savedTransforms = [];
      var save = ctx.save;
      ctx.save = function(){
          savedTransforms.push(xform.translate(0,0));
          return save.call(ctx);
      };
    
      var restore = ctx.restore;
      ctx.restore = function(){
        xform = savedTransforms.pop();
        return restore.call(ctx);
        };

      var scale = ctx.scale;
      ctx.scale = function(sx,sy){
        xform = xform.scaleNonUniform(sx,sy);
        return scale.call(ctx,sx,sy);
        };
    
      var rotate = ctx.rotate;
      ctx.rotate = function(radians){
          xform = xform.rotate(radians*180/Math.PI);
          return rotate.call(ctx,radians);
      };
    
      var translate = ctx.translate;
      ctx.translate = function(dx,dy){
          xform = xform.translate(dx,dy);
          return translate.call(ctx,dx,dy);
      };
    
      var transform = ctx.transform;
      ctx.transform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
          var m2 = svg.createSVGMatrix();
          m2.a=a; m2.b=b; m2.c=c; m2.d=d; m2.e=e; m2.f=f;
          xform = xform.multiply(m2);
          return transform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
      };
    
      var setTransform = ctx.setTransform;
      ctx.setTransform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
          xform.a = a;
          xform.b = b;
          xform.c = c;
          xform.d = d;
          xform.e = e;
          xform.f = f;
          return setTransform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
      };
    
      var pt  = svg.createSVGPoint();
      ctx.transformedPoint = function(x,y){
          pt.x=x; pt.y=y;
          return pt.matrixTransform(xform.inverse());
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            canvas {
                border: thin solid black;
            }
            body{
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas></canvas>
        <script src="tester.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm very new to javascript so please help in any way possible. If at all possible please explain what you are doing and why as I'd like to understand the code better rather than just having something that works.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `scale(x, y)` function call inside the `zoom` method is the one that handles zooming. The scale function takes two arguments x and y, x says how much the context should be scaled along the x-axis and y for its counterpart.

So, what you could do is maintain a global variable that stores current zoom level and check against it every time the zoom action is triggered.

You can extend the same idea to bound the panning (taken care by `mousedown` and `mousemove` methods). Maintain global values that track the current position and check it against the scale and boundaries every time a pan action is triggered.